# How can I set up reserved word for particular column in validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a model called `Community` and it has a column called `name`

I use this `name` in sub-domain.

For example, when a user access to `http://rockstar.test-sample.com`, it show the same content as `http://test-sample.com/community/rockstar`

obviously, this `name` shouldn't be `www`

How can I prohibit `www` if I'm stating that in `models/community.rb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to spend some time with the [Active Record Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion):

> **2.4 exclusion**
>
> This helper validates that the attributes' values are not included in a given set. In fact, this set can be any enumerable object.
>
> ```
> class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
>   validates :subdomain, exclusion: { in: %w(www us ca jp),
>     message: "Subdomain %{value} is reserved." }
> end
> ```

So something like this in your model should do the trick:

```
validates :name, :exclusion => { in: %w[www] }
```

Comment: I tried this but it still returns error:( `validates :name, :exclusion => { in: %w[www] }, message: "has to be other than www"`

Comment: There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.

Comment: and I take it back. It can contain www but cannot be exactly www. so wwwoie is okay.

Comment: @muistooshort `There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.`

Comment: That's an error from Passenger. @MKK post the actual error message, further down the page under "Error message:"

Comment: sorry about that I was missing  last `}` now everything works fine. Thanks guys:)