# How can I set up reserved word for particular column in validation with case insensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a question [same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668456/how-can-i-set-up-reserved-word-for-particular-column-in-validation) but with `case_sensitive: false`. I thought it's best to create a new question rather than asking the question in a comment.

My model is like:

```rb
validates   :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}, exclusion: {in: %w(all delete deleted archived archive),
    message: "The group name %{value} is reserved." }
```

The `name` column is not made lowercase. If I save with, ie, "all", it blocks it. If save it "All", it saves. I don't want that. How to achieve this? These should fail the validation: "all, alL, ALL" etc and same for others.

Comment: Easiest way is to make a custom validation that checks to see if the lowercase value of the column is in the list.

Comment: @dbugger yup, that was the last thing to do but I thought there was a "one-liner" I could use. Thanks.